# Operaciones con timestamp en mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla que almacena unos registros y uno de los campos es `fecha` este es de tipo *timestamp* y se añade sola al hacer `update`

```
ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
```

Lo que necesito es eliminar los registros de mas de 7 días pero no consigo hacerlo.

[image: Columna fecha]

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado y qué errores te arroja?

Comment: He intentado muchas opciones, y unasme devuelven todas las filas de la tabla y otras no me devuelven ninguna, errores no he tenido.Lo primero que probe fue DELETE FROM info_tolvas_log
WHERE fecha < fecha + 72*3600, ahi me di cuenta que las operaciones con timestamp no eran tan sencillas, despues intente hacer SELECT * FROM info_tolvas_log WHERE
CAST(fecha AS DATE) >= NOW()
AND fecha < DATE_ADD( NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY )

Comment: Como veis el problema es mi desconocmiento en las operaciones con timestamp y por mas que busco no consigo aclararme

Comment: Simplemente esto debería funcionar:  **`SELECT * FROM info_tolvas_log WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(),fecha) > 7;`**  Revisa si te trae los registros que deben ser borrados y entonces la cambias a `DELETE`

Comment: Muchismias gracias, funciono, pues si que era simpe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar [`DATEDIFF()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) para calcular cuantos días han transcurrido entre la fecha actual (`NOW()`)  y la columna de la tabla (`fecha`).

Por ejemplo, esta consulta borrará todos los registros cuya `fecha` sea mayor a `7`:

```
DELETE FROM info_tolvas_log WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(),fecha) > 7
```

**Recomendaciones:**

- Prueba las consultas de modificación masiva sobre datos de prueba.
- Considera hacer un backup antes de ejecutar consultas de este tipo por si algo falla.
- Considera hacer un backup regular de la base de datos.